# How do I change a partial view with a radio button click in .Net MVC and have some of the model state passed along to the partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button, partial-views

I'm trying to display a partial view in a div block named 'productButtonForm' based on a radio button click. The partial view appears to be called, but the passed model has null member variables. Can someone help me figure out where I've gone wrong? Below is what I've got:

**Model**

```
public class RetrieveAllModel
{
    public Guid ConversationId { get; set; }
    public List<RetrieveProductsModel> Products { get; set; }
    public RetrieveOffersModel Offers { get; set; }
    public int ProductType { get; set; }

}
```

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Easy Order";
    int productCount = 0;
 }

<legend>Offers/Products</legend>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowProductItems", "BrowseShopping"))
{

    foreach (var type in Model.Products)
    {
        if (productCount > 0 && productCount % 5 == 0)
        {
            <br/>//break after every 5 products
        }
        @type.Name
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ProductType, type.ID, Model);
        <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        productCount = productCount + 1;
    }
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="productButtonForm">
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult ShowProductItems()
{
    return PartialView("RetrieveProducts", new RetrieveAllModel() {Products = new List<RetrieveProductsModel>()});
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ShowProductItems(RetrieveAllModel model)
{
    //The passed model only has the ProductType set, every other 
    //member variable is null
    return PartialView("RetrieveProducts", model);
}
```

**Script file**

```
$(function() {
$("[name=ProductType]").on('change',
    function() {
        var $radio = $(this);
        var myurl = "ShowProductItems?ProductType=" + $radio.val();
        console.log("We hit the script");
        $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#productButtonForm").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The only value your sending in the request is one for `ProductType` (as a query string value) so that is the only property that will be bound. And note the 3rd parameter in `RadiobuttonFor()` is the html attributes, so using `Model` in your case makes no sense

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I'm still getting used to .Net, it's so-called MVC pattern, and add-ons like Razor and HTML helpers. I've been using Vaadin for the past few years for Web application development and it's no where near as convoluted as what I've run into the past week. I've been mucking around with my code today and realized both of the things you've pointed out. Do you have a suggestion for passing more than a string value into the controller (i.e the entire current Model state) when a radio button is clicked?

Comment: First you should not be submitting a form when a radio button is clicked. And this has nothing to do with mvc - its basic html/http - if you want the server to receive information, then you need to send it to the server. I have no idea what you really want to do here. If you want to send other values for properties in your model then you need to include those values in the request.

Comment: Fantastic! You've helped me narrow my problem down. So how do I send complex types to the controller? In traditional MVC, the Controller has complete knowledge of both the model and view states. So I'm some what confused by the notion of having to pass model state to the controller.

Comment: What do you mean in _traditional MVC_. I assume you must be referring to web forms which uses `ViewState` (which is not MVC). If you want to bind all properties of your model, then your must create form inputs for those properties and submit the form (or at least serialize the values to javascript variables are submit them in your ajax call. But if you not editing any of those values then that would be pointless. Again its no clear what your wanting to do. If you need the whole model, then include the ID of the model in the request and get the model again in the POST method

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Your mention of the model Id helped me think of a working solution. I've posted my solution below for the edification of others needing to cause a view change based on a radio button click. Btw, by _traditional MVC_  I mean the world outside .NET , where the MVC design pattern involves the controller having full knowledge of the model without the client having to provide that information. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a few issues going. Aside from what Stephen mentioned above, I had two data models that needed to be represented in the same button group. To address that, I had to use Html.RadioButton instead of RadionButtonFor. Also, I needed to access the controller's established conversation with the client to access the model state of the current view. Once I got those in place, the partial view changes as desired. Below are the changes I made to fix my triggering problem.

**Model**

```
public class RetrieveAllModel
{
    public Guid ConversationId { get; set; }
    public List<RetrieveProductsModel> Products { get; set; }
    public RetrieveOffersModel Offers { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }

}

public class RetrieveCatalogModel
{
    public List<BrowseDataItemModel> AvailableBrowseItems { get; set; }
}

public class RetrieveOffersModel : RetrieveCatalogModel
{
    public List<int> SelectedServiceIds { get; set; }
}

public class RetrieveProductsModel : RetrieveCatalogModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model OrderServiceClient.Models.RetrieveAllModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Easy Order";
    int productCount = 1;
    string offers = "Offers";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowCatalog", "BrowseShopping"))
{
    //since offers are not part of the dynamic product list, they need to be specifically identified
    @offers<label>&nbsp;</label>
    @Html.RadioButton("catalogName", "Offers", true, new { catalogName = "Offers", conversationid = Model.ConversationId })
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    foreach (var type in Model.Products)
    {
        if (productCount > 0 && productCount % 5 == 0)
        {
            <br/>//break after every 5 products
        }
        @type.Name<label>&nbsp;</label>
        @Html.RadioButton("catalogName", type.Name, new { catalogName = type.Name, conversationid = Model.ConversationId })
        <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        productCount = productCount + 1;
    }
}

...

<div class="row">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("RetrieveCatalogs", Model.Offers.AvailableBrowseItems);}
</div>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model List<OrderServiceClient.Models.BrowseDataItemModel>

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12 offers-container" id="shoppingcatalog">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Data Type</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr class="offerList">
                    <td>@item.DataType</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@string.Format($"{item.Amount,0:C2}")</td>
                    <td><a class="addService" dataType="@item.DataType" serviceId="@item.ServiceId" serviceName="@item.Name" amount="@item.Amount">Add</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public PartialViewResult ShowCatalog()
    {
        RetrieveCatalogModel rcm = new RetrieveCatalogModel();
        rcm.AvailableBrowseItems = new List<BrowseDataItemModel>();
        return PartialView("RetrieveCatalogs", rcm.AvailableBrowseItems);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult ShowCatalog(string catalogName, Guid conversationid)
    {
        if (catalogName.Equals("Offers"))
        {
            RetrieveOffersModel offers = new RetrieveOffersModel();
            var response = BrowseShoppingHelper.RetrieveOffers(conversationid, _client);
            offers.AvailableBrowseItems = BuildOffersBrowseDataItemsModel(response).ToList();

            return PartialView("RetrieveCatalogs", offers.AvailableBrowseItems);
        }
        else
        {
            var prodctFolderResponse = BrowseShoppingHelper.RetrieveProductFolders(conversationid, _client);
            var output = (RetrieveProductFoldersCommandOutput) prodctFolderResponse.Body.Output;
            RetrieveProductsModel rpm = new RetrieveProductsModel{Name = catalogName, AvailableBrowseItems = new List<BrowseDataItemModel>()};
            foreach (var folder in output.Folders)
            {
                if (!catalogName.Equals(folder.Name)) continue;
                var items = BuildProductBrowseItemsModel(
                    (RetrieveProductsInGroupCommandOutput) BrowseShoppingHelper
                        .RetrieveProductItems(conversationid, _client, folder).Body.Output);
                rpm.AvailableBrowseItems.AddRange(items);
                break;
            }
            return PartialView("RetrieveCatalogs", rpm.AvailableBrowseItems);
        }
    }
```

**Script file**

```
$(function() {
$("[name=catalogName]").on('change',
    function () {
        var $radio = $(this);
        var myurl = "ShowCatalog?catalogName=" + $radio.val() + "&conversationid=" + $(this).attr('conversationid');
        console.log("Catalog item is: " + $radio.val() + " and id is: " + $(this).attr('conversationid'));
        $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#shoppingcatalog").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```